# Huge empty space in chrome timeline and gray bar

Tags: performance, web, google-chrome-devtools, timeline, developer-tools

I'm testing performance of a webpage that is slow. Checking it on Chrome timeline, I see a huge white space before the loading, represented by a gray bar that is almost 2.2 seconds long. I don't understand what this bar represents and what I can do to fix it.

I also see that the page is loaded twice (there are two blocks on the timeline). I would like to understand exactly what does the refresh, because that isn't supposed to happen.

[image: Chrome Timeline]

Comment: FWIW, it's not loaded twice. The green vertical line is the first paint, the blue one is `DOMContentLoaded`, red: `load`. As for the gray bar, maybe it's a bug or leftover from something? Try in a newer Chrome Canary, or simply restart the browser.